# How to let Query are performed at the component onmount and triggered by user event later?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

My page has a search form and table with a paginator. So I have two states: `searchCondition` and `pagination`. I need to query the `channelList` when the page component is mounted.

When the user clicks the paginator, the `pagination` state will be changed so that a new `channelList` query will be made. That's ok.

The search form includes two input form items and a "Query" button. The `channelList` query also can be triggered by the user click event.

But now, when the user types something in the input form item. The `channelList` query is made immediately when the `searchCondition` state changed. That's not expected. I want this query triggered when the user clicks the "Query" button.

I read the doc [Dependent Queries](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/dependent-queries), there is an `enabled` option, but don't think it can solve my issue.

Currently:

- Send the query on the component mount. - done!
- Made a new query when `pagination` state changed - done!
- User types something in the input form item(this will cause the `searchCondition` state changed) and clicks the "Query" button, then made a new query - undone.

When sending the `channelList` query, I will make the API parameters by merging `searchCondition` and `pagination` states.

```
const { searchCondition, setSearchCondition } = useSearchCondition(initialSearchCondition);
const { pagination, setPagination } = usePagination();
const channelListQuery = useQuery(
  ['channelList', pagination, searchCondition],
  async () => {
    const getChannelListParams = omitFalsyFields({
      currentPage: pagination.current,
      pageSize: pagination.pageSize,
      ...searchCondition,
    });
    const { code, result } = await apis.channel.getChannelList(getChannelListParams);
    if (code === '0') {
      return result;
    }
  },
  { initialData: { totalItem: 0, resultList: [] }, refetchOnWindowFocus: false, keepPreviousData: true },
);
```

Answer (score 5):

> But now, when the user types something in the input form item. The channelList query is made immediately when the searchCondition state changed. That's not expected. I want this query triggered when the user clicks the "Query" button.

What you need for this to happen is to have two state. One inside the form so that users can type (this can also be an uncontrolled form), and another one that you set when the user clicks the "Query" button.

That second state is what your query should "listen to" - by being part of the query key. Pseudo code:

```
function App() {
 const [search, setSearch] = useState()
 const { data } = useQuery(['channelList', search], () => getChannelList(search), { enabled: !!search }

 <SearchFrom onSubmit={setSearch} />
}
```

by making sure to only call `setSearch` when the user clicks the `Query` button, you make sure that the query doesn't fire on every click.

A good place to store "applied searches" is also the url: When the user clicks the button, you write to the url, and the query subscribes to that.

This also makes your urls sharable, which is nice.

I have a short example on that here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-query-url-filtering-h0ikw?file=/src/App.tsx

The filter form itself is uncontrolled - but it doesn't really matter how you solve it, it's "internal" to the filter form. The "global" client state lives in the url.

Comment: How do I create API parameters by merging `pagination` and `searchCondition` if I do this? That's why I have two deps when using `useQuery` like `useQuery(['channelList', search, pagination], ...)`

Comment: Besides, my form component is a controlled component. This means the state will be set in `onChange` event handler of each form item rather than `onSubmit`

Comment: Should I have another state called `isFormSubmited: boolean` and use it like `enabled: isFormSubmited`?

Comment: if your form is controlled, it should still pass the state via an `onSubmit` callback to the parent. The parent can then also store it an let that state drive the query.